# Can't get my helper to return results

Tags: php, codeigniter

So I thought I'd write my first codeigniter helper (still new to codeigniter somewhat).  I needed something that would return an array of filenames from a photo directory to make hyperlinks to them. This was so I wouldn't have to write out each filename myself, and adding new photos to the directory dynamically updated the site.

So I made a new helper called `photo_helper.php` which looks like this:

```
<?php 

    function spit_out_images($path)
    {
        $aryPhotos = get_filenames($path);

        //does parsing to create hyperlinks

        return $aryPhotos;
    }
```

I set the `file` and `photo` helper to autoload inside my `autoload.php`

Then in my view I called the helper function `spit_out_images` like so:

```
<?php
      $photoPath = base_url().'assets/_images/TwentyYears/thumbs';
      echo spit_out_images($photoPath);

?>
```

But I never get any results out.  I even tried echoing out the `$photoPath` variable to make sure it was giving out the path correctly, which it was.

I'm sure it is something simple I'm missing, I just can't figure it out.

Thank you!

Comment: Is `get_filenames()` returning anything? What does `var_dump(spit_out_images($photoPath));` output?

Comment: Does your helper includes a recursive function?

Comment: var_dump() returns `bool(false)` but I'm not sure what that means.  I tried just using `get_filesnames($photoPath)` but it doesn't return anything.  There's photos in the directory though.

Comment: @drpcken: The problem clearly is with the `get_filenames()` function.

Comment: Right but isn't it just a helper in Codeigniter?  I have the file helper loaded.

Comment: @drpcken: Yes, I took a look at the source code and the problem seems to be the `@opendir()` call. I think it doesn't have the necessary filesystem permissions.

Comment: @drpcken: From the manual (http://php.net/manual/en/function.opendir.php): **If path is not a valid directory or the directory can not be opened due to permission restrictions or filesystem errors, opendir() returns FALSE and generates a PHP error of level E_WARNING. You can suppress the error output of opendir() by prepending '@' to the front of the function name**.

Comment: Ah thank you Alix, apparently the FILE helper doesn't like using URL's (base_url()).   Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure `base_url() . 'assets/_images/TwentyYears/thumbs'` has the correct permissions for Apache/PHP to execute and read the directory and files, `0755` should be an appropriate mode.

Comment: It worked when I removed the base_url().  It returned the array.  Should I change permissions or just use the direct path without the http://baseurl in front of it?

Comment: @drpcken: My bad, I didn't even noticed you were calling `base_url()`! `get_filenames()` is a filesystem function, it has nothing to do with the HTTP protocol nor URLs, so just drop it. You shouldn't need to change the permissions.

Comment: I feel like you deserve the answer for pointing me in the right direction :)

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you don't have read access from that directory. You can check directory permissions using filezilla, but to change you will need ssh access .